# Looking for faster way to filter integer from string - Python 3.3

Tags: python, filter, python-3.3

I am trying to dissect an integer from data gathered by another beautifulsoup script I wrote.
The data I get is always one of the three following:

```
<div id="counts"> 500 hits </div>
<div id="counts">3 hits </div>
<div id="counts"> hits </div>
```

The number of hits varies and is sometimes attached to the ">" and sometimes not. And other times the integer isn't there. So I wrote this script to return ONLY the number from the data (or tell me there is no number). It seems clunky and slow and I feel like there should be a faster way to do it? (in this code example, I included 'search' as one of the 3 possible outcomes of the bs scrape)

```
keywords = ['hits']
results = []
search = '<div id="hits"> 3 hits </div>'

num_check = False
store_next = False
words = search.split()

def is_number(results, num_check):
    while num_check <= 0:
        try:
            float(results[0])
            num_check = True
        except ValueError:
            results[0] = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), results[0]))
            if results[0] == '':
                num_check = 2
    if num_check <= 1:
        print(results[0])

for word in reversed(words):
    if store_next:
        results.append(word)
        store_next = False
    elif word in keywords:
        store_next = True

is_number(results, num_check)
```

EDIT: sometimes (rarely) the `<div></div>` contains more info, such as a ping speed `(0.22 seconds)`, which is why I can't search the entire clause for integers.

Comment: Not really an answer, but fyi, `''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), results[0]))` can be rewritten to simply `filter(str.isdigit, results[0])`

Comment: It seems better to have your other script generate just the `text` of each tag instead of the `repr` of the whole `Tag`, no?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number` on line 12 after it filters. If I try `print(filter(str.isdigit, '<div id="hits">3'))` I get `<filter object at 0x00000000032BA160>` printed.

Comment: @roippi That's true but sadly sometimes the `<div>` section contains extra info which is why I have to work back from `hits`

Comment: http://ideone.com/v35d5Q will show you how to get a string back from filter in python 3 ... in python2 it just stays a string

Comment: @Gronk, sorry for misinforming you. I'm on python2 here. The lambda was unnecessary, but the join apparently was not

Answer (score 2):

ummm maybe

```
search = '<div id="hits"> 3 hits </div>'
re.findall("\d+",search)
```

or for floats

```
re.findall("\d+\.?\d*",search)
```

if you know theres not going to be more than one at a time you could do

```
re.search("(\d+)",search).group(0)
```

here is some timing info

```
>>> timeit.timeit("re.search(\"(\d+)\",'<div id=\"hits\"> 3 hits </div>').group(   0)","import re",number = 1000)
0.0031895773144583472
>>> timeit.timeit("filter(str.isdigit, '<div id=\"hits\"> 3 hits </div>')",numbe   r=1000)
0.0049939576031476918
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have added in my post that occasionally there is ping info like `0.22 seconds' contained in the `<div></div>`. I have edited the post to add that info. I had not thought of this though and would work most of the time.

Comment: how bout `re.search("(\d+) hits",search_text)` that should only match the pattern shown

Comment: do you mean `re.search("(\d+) hits",search)`? If `search = '<div id="hits">3,153 hits 476.12 seconds </div>` the `re.` function returns `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000032FA918>`

Comment: Sorry, more info: if I: `s = re.search("(\d+) hits",search` when I return `s.group()` it only gives `153 hits` which means it seems to be stopping at the comma.